# Replacing NaN in multiindex column, and replace with dictionary key value pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have one multiindex dataframe and one separate dictionary:
multiindex df:

[image]

dictionary:
[image]

I want to replace all NaNs in only PRICE2, and in each subcolumn value (AH2319, etc) with the corresponding key value pair in dictionary. (Key in dict is the subcolumn name and the value in dict should replace the NaNs in the dataframe)

Hoe can I do it in Python?

Comment: [Formatted Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) are preferred to images of Tables as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily if you modify your dictionary:

```
d = {'FY9121': [160], ...}`   --->    `d = {'FY9121': 160, ...}`
```

Now, you can use `fillna`:

```
df['PRICE2'] = df['PRICE2'].fillna(d)
```

Comment: I modified the dictionary, but adding the .fillna still gives me the same result (without errors). Any help on why it might be happening?